# Using Pointers and strtok()

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I'm building a linked list and need your assistance please as I'm new to C.
I need to input a string that looks like this: `(word)_#_(year)_#_(DEFINITION(UPPER CASE))`

Ex: Enter a string
Input: `invest_#_1945_#_TRADE`

Basically I'm looking to build a function that scans the DEFINITION and give's me back the word it relates to.
Enter a word to search in the dictionary
Input: TRADE
Output: Found "TREADE" in the word "invest"

So far I managed to come up using the strtok() function but right now I'm not sure what to do about printing the first word then.

Here's what I could come up with:

```
  char split(char words[99],char *p)
 {

p=strtok(words, "_#_");
while (p!=NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n",p);
    p = strtok(NULL, "_#_");
}
return 0;

 }


 int main()
 {
char hello[99];
char *s = NULL;

printf("Enter a string you want to split\n");
scanf("%s", hello);
split(hello,s);
return 0;
 }
```

Any ideas on what should I do?

Comment: sorry guys having trouvle editing

Comment: Remove unwanted data, why have the struct when it's referenced nowhere.

Comment: Take a look at `strstr()`

Comment: Okay sorry for my struct i accidentally included there i'll take it out.
I have all the functions needed for the linked list
I'm looking to scan my strings and have a function that will scan my DEFINITION and give the word it relates to exactly on the example i showed above

Comment: `strtok()` looks for any character in the string, look at `strstr()` as @wildplasser said

Comment: okay I'll have a look at it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon that your problem is how to extract the three bits of information from your formatted string.

The function `strtok` does not work as you think it does: The second argument is not a literal delimiting string, but a string that serves as a set of characters that are delimiters.

In your case, `sscanf` seems to be the better choice:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char *line = "invest_#_1945 _#_TRADE  ";

    char word[40];
    int year;
    char def[40];
    int n;

    n = sscanf(line, "%40[^_]_#_%d_#_%40s", word, &year, def);

    if (n == 3) {
        printf("word:   %s\n", word);
        printf("year:   %d\n", year);
        printf("def'n:  %s\n", def);
    } else {
        printf("Unrecognized line.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The function `sscanf` examines a given string according to a given pattern. Roughly, that pattern consists of format specifiers that begin with a percent sign, of spaces which denote any amount of white-space characters (including none) and of other characters that have to be matched varbatim. The format specifiers yield a result, which has to be stored. Therefore, for each specifier, a result variable must be given after the format string.

In this case, there are several chunks:

`%40[^_]` reads up to 40 characters that are not the underscore into a char array. This is a special case of reading a string. Strings in `sscanf` are really words and may not contain white space. The underscore, however, would be part of a string, so in order not to eat up the underscore of the first delimiter, you have to use the notation `[^(chars)]`, which means: Any sequence of chars that do not contain the given chars. (The caret does the negation here, `[(chars)]` would mean any sequence of the given chars.)

`_#_` matches the first delimiter literally, i.e. only if the next chars are underscore hash mark, underscore.

`%d` reads a decimal number into an integer. Note that the adress of the integer has to be given here with `&`.

`_#_` matches the second delimiter.

`%40s` reads a string of up to 40 non-whitespace characters into a char array.

The function returns the number of matched results, which should be three if the line is valid. The function `sscanf` can be cumbersome, but is probably your best bet here for quick and dirty input.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strtokByWord_r(char *str, const char *word, char **store){
    char *p, *ret;
    if(str != NULL){
        *store = str;
    }
    if(*store == NULL) return NULL;
    p = strstr(ret=*store, word);
    if(p){
        *p='\0';
        *store = p + strlen(word);
    } else {
        *store = NULL;
    }
    return ret;
}
char *strtokByWord(char *str, const char *word){
    static char *store = NULL;
    return strtokByWord_r(str, word, &store);
}

int main(){
    char input[]="invest_#_1945_#_TRADE";
    char *array[3];
    char *p;
    int i, size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(char*);
    for(i=0, p=input;i<size;++i){
        if(NULL!=(p=strtokByWord(p, "_#_"))){
            array[i]=p;//strdup(p);
            p=NULL;
        } else {
            array[i]=NULL;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i<size;++i)
        printf("array[%d]=\"%s\"\n", i, array[i]);
/* result
array[0]="invest"
array[1]="1945"
array[2]="TRADE"
*/
    return 0;
}
```