# Use of strtok()

Tags: c, string

I'm having a problem using strtok().
I have a string i'm inputing and it's supposed to take the `_#_` off and leave the rest. The problem is that it also deletes the `_` and i need it to specifically delete `_#_`.

This is my code here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char *strtok( char *str1, const char *str2 );

  char str[] = "hello_#_there_#_my__name_#_is_#_sam";

  char delims[] = "_#_";
  char *result = NULL;

  result = strtok( str, delims );

  while( result != NULL )
  {
    printf( "%s", result );
    result = strtok( NULL, delims );
  }

  return 0;

}
```

This is what it's returning me:
hellotheremynameissam

This is what i'm trying to have
hellotheremy__nameissam

Any ideas?

Comment: `strtok` doesn't seem to support multi-character delimiters.

Comment: what would you recommend me doing?

Comment: Write your own tokeniser or try to find a library that does it for you.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20868422/971127

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Pointers and strtok()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868252/using-pointers-and-strtok)

Comment: not a duplicate but same guy asking

Answer (score 2):

The delimiters indicate which characters to tokenize on.  It does not indicate to match the string.  It will find all _ and # characters.  Look at strstr()

Answer (score 1):

```
char delims[] = "_#_";
...
result = strtok( str, delims );
```

...means that *any* of the characters in the string, not the string itself, will be used as delimiter.

As an alternative, if you instead use `strstr` to find the full delimiter, you'd end up with something like;

```
char str[] = "hello_#_there_#_my__name_#_is_#_sam";

char delim[] = "_#_";
char *position = str;
char *result;

/* While there's at least one more delimiter */
while ((result = strstr(position, delim)) != NULL) 
{
    printf("%.*s", result - position, position); /* Print up to next delimiter */
    position = result + 3;                       /* Skip the delimiter         */
}

printf("%s", position);                          /* Print the remainder        */
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search for `_#_` repeatedly & print what is between each pair of occurrences (which is what you're doing w/ strtok), but you have to keep track of where to start each print from.

Comment: strtok() does not search for the character sequence, it searches for any of the characters.

Comment: Which might be why I did not say to use strtok.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20869528/905902

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general `remove_delims()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
remove_delims(char *str, char *delim)
{
    size_t delim_len;
    char *result, *middle0, *middle1;

    delim_len = strlen(delim);
    if ((result = malloc(strlen(str) + 1)) == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    middle0 = str;
    for (;;) {
        if ((middle1 = strstr(middle0, delim)) == NULL) {
            strcat(result, middle0);
            return result;
        }
        else {
            strncat(result, middle0, middle1 - middle0);
            middle0 = middle1 + delim_len;
        }
    }
}


int
main(void)
{
    char *strs[] = {
        "",
        "test1",
        "_#_",
        "_#_test1",
        "_#_test1_#_",
        "_#_test1_#_test2",
        "test1_#_",
        "test1_#_test2",
        "hello_#_there_#_my__name_#_is_#_sam",
        NULL,
    };
    char delim[] = "_#_";
    char *result, *str;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; (str = strs[i]); i++) {
        result = remove_delims(str, delim);
        printf("%-32s\t%s\n", str, result);
        free(result);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```