# Using strtok() on Linked List

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I'm new to c and I'm trying to build a doubly linked list.
I have a small concern which I would like your help please.
I need to input a string that looks like this:

```
(word)_#_(year)_#_(english synonyms)_#_(hebrew synonyms)
```

And in fact I need to store each word on my linked list so I used strtok() to separate the `_#_` symbol. The problem here is when I'm inputting my string to test if I can separate it but it gives me the following message:

> Program Using strtok()(39583,0x7fff7a83f310) malloc: *** error for
>   object 0x7fff5fbff668: pointer being freed was not allocated

Now i think i found the problem though i can't resolve it. 
Here's my code i put a comment on my program where the problem is. Would love your help

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 typedef struct dictionary {
 char word[100];
 int year[10];
 char eng_synonyms[100];
 char heb_synonyms[100]; } dictionary;

dictionary parse_dictionary(const char *s) {
 char *copy = strdup(s); // Make a copy for strtok
 char *tok = strtok(copy, "_#_");
 dictionary result = {0};

 if (tok != NULL)
 {
     result.word[99] = *strdup(tok);
 }
 else
 {
     result.word[99] = *strdup("");
 }

 tok = strtok(NULL, "_#_");

 if (tok != NULL)
 {
     result.year[9] = *strdup(tok);
 }
 else
 {
     result.year[9] = *strdup("");
 }

 tok = strtok(NULL, "_#_");
 if (tok != NULL)
 {
     result.eng_synonyms[99] = *strdup(tok);
 }
 else
 {
     result.eng_synonyms[99] = *strdup("");
 }
 free(copy); // Clean up temporaries
 return result; }

   int main(void) {
 char dictionarys[100];
 printf("Enter a string\n");
 scanf("%s", dictionarys);

 dictionary def = parse_dictionary(dictionarys);
 printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", def.word, def.year, def.eng_synonyms, def.heb_synonyms); // format specifies char* but argument has type *int
 free(def.word);
 free(def.year);
 free(def.eng_synonyms);
 free(def.heb_synonyms);
 return 0; }
```

Comment: case `char word[100]` : `strcpy(result.word, tok);`, case `char *word` : `result.word = strdup(tok);`

Comment: `format specifies char* but argument has type *int` because `year` is an array of `int` (not a string)

Comment: and strtok not be used to cut out the token by string. Because separator in strtok it is not a string. it's character(separator list).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20868252/905902

Answer (score 2):

You should not call free on static object. E.g.  `def.word` is an static array of size 100 and you should not free it same goes for the other structure members. Free should only be called for objects allocated dynamically(using `malloc` for instance).

Answer (score 0):

The line of code `result.word[99] = *strdup(tok);` is setting the 99th character of the static array `result.word` to the first character of `tok`(the `*` is dereferencing the first character only). You should use `strcpy` or `memcpy`([memcpy reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/?kw=memcpy)) instead to copy the value of `tok` to `result.word`.

Also it is good practice to zero fill a structure before using it by using a function like `memset` ([memset reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/?kw=memset))

```
dictionary result;
memset(&result,0,sizeof(dictionary));
```

For the `int year[10]` member of `dictionary`, it doesn't make sense that it is an array. It should be a plain `int`. You need to read it as a `char*` then convert it to `int` using function `atoi` ([atoi reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/?kw=atoi)).